# How to inspect different alternatives when travelling a list

Tags: prolog

I have to write a program that given a list of "structs", workers, and the time they spend working, I find out which given pair of workers, and wich order, is the correct to do the job in time.

Example: TotalTime=40. If I have worker1=15 (minutes, or whatever), worker2=20, worker3=5.

Let's say that given a certain criteria (sum of the times has to be less than total, and last two have to finish at the same time), I accept or reject an input.

What I would like to know is, how to run again all over the list, picking different workers this time.

Which means, I can understand travelling a list in prolog, you pick what you need, operate, recursion to travel the list, get a solution, go up and get said solution. But if that particular solution does not meet the criteria (which in my case I believe you can not know if it fits unless you went until the last worker (or if you picked bad values like 1 worker alone goes beyond the limit given), how do I would program: **travel the list again, picking different options this time.**

Comment: When you say *which given pair of workers, and which order, is the correct to do the job in time*, what does "correct" mean? Are you referring to the order within a pair of workers? And why does that matter? There's not quite enough information here to really help, other than to say that this is probably just a case of backtracking to traverse possible list options. Worst case, it might involve collecting possible solutions and picking the "best" with `bagof/3`, but again, it's unclear.

Comment: I meant that I need to solve the problem in a certain way. This is homeworks so it's not like I wanted to keep it obstuse, it was so not to write out the exact problem so people would not get annoyed over it. I want to get a general idea on how to attack this problem, and I'm trying to explain myself as best as I can, chopping the problem in the smallest units I can.

Comment: Problem with backtracking and this problem I have, is that if a certain combination of workers does not meet that "correct" way, I have to try again, starting with a different couple of workers. Is that try again thing one of the concepts I do not see right now.

Comment: I understand the desire not to be too specific. :) The determination of the "correct" way must be some kind of condition you can apply which, when the condition fails, further backtracking occurs. I know, though, it's probably not that simple (or you wouldn't be asking :)). Sometimes, though, it's a matter of finding the right relational perspective on the problem. As you traverse the list, you would "collect" what may be a candidate solution which would ultimately be rejected if the condition stops being true.